# Can I sell 808 style drum sound library?

Tags: sound-design, library

I am wondering if I am able to sell 808 style drums sound library? I am confused on the topic from a legal stand point if the 808 drums are copyrighted or not. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can - if you recorded it.

TR-808 is a synthesizer, and if you record or create any works with it, it is just like any other synthesizer.....you own the works.

Also if you create 808 inspired sounds with another synthesizer, you own that as well. Roland can not copyright a sine wave with a pitch envelope on it, or a noise generator.

I have recorded a TR-808 for a [drum app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mb8008) I made..though I don't charge for it.

Comment: Thank you Scott for the straight forward answer! Have a great day!

Comment: Don't forget to set as answer.